How do you fix these corners?
I’ve pretty much solved this but these two corners are on the opposite ends

Remove a center piece, then get a screwdriver, then take the cube apart. Then reassamble it correctly. Solved!

This is impossible to solve using only normal cube moves. There are two reasons for that. The first is that it is impossible to swap two corner pieces while keeping the rest solved (as explained here ). The second is that it is impossible to twist a single corner without twisting any others (as explained here ). You will have to partially disassemble the cube to fix it.
